# Uncaught at initializeDrizzle TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, drizzle

I am working a Drizzle truffle box project, and this is my first intro to React so I am struggling a little bit. I keep getting this error and I cannot for the life of me seem to fix it.

The contract ABI is getting passed in successfully and I have made sure the contract is referenced in Drizzle Options. I'm baffled as to why this is happening. Please advise. I can provide any other info as necessary

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33706156/44631233-2ee73580-a937-11e8-8214-307f1214c902.png

Anyone have any ideas? Here is a link to the code repo for the whole project. https://github.com/hashoshi/nft_token_project

**FIXED repo link**

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much in that repo. :-)

Comment: fixed... ugh lol

Comment: long day, sorry for the missing repo files

Comment: Did you do any progress on this? I am having the same problem. also the `context` that is everywhere in the documentation is always empty.